# ¿Cómo reemplazar/modificar un caracter determinado de un string en Python?

Tags: python, string

¿Cómo se realizaría el reemplazo de un determinado caracter de un string en Python? Por ejemplo, si tenemos el siguiente String:

```
ejemplo = "pytfon"
```

para reemplazar el caracter **f** por **h**, ¿Cómo se procede a modificarlo? De forma que quede:

```
ejemplo = "python"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar `.replace()`

```
ejemplo="pytfon"
ejemplo = ejemplo.replace('f','h')
print(ejemplo)
```

Reemplazará todos los caracteres 'f' por 'h'

Si quieres limitar solo a la primera ocurrencia:

```
ejemplo="pytfonf"
ejemplo = ejemplo.replace('f','h',1)
print(ejemplo)
```

Produce:

```
pythonf
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Por medio de un índice

```
ejemplo = ejemplo[:3] + "h" + ejemplo[4:]
```

El índice, es la posición del caracter que queremos modificar. Se divide la cadena en dos partes que no incluyan el caracter a reeemplazar. Para mayor comodidad:

```
def replace_at(cadena, idx, char):
  return cadena[:idx] + char + cadena[idx+1:]
```

#### Por caracter

```
ejemplo = ejemplo.replace("f", "h")
```

Nota: este método reemplaza todas las ocurrencias de `"f"`, puedes usar el parámetro `count` para indicar cuantos reemplazos hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Los strings son inmutables, asi que hay que producir un nuevo string.

Alternativa: Convertirlo a lista, cambiarlo (por indice) y de vuelta a string:

```
def replace_at(texto, pos, car):
    """ Reemplaza caracter en el texto

    @param texto: El texto donde reemplazar.
    @param pos: Indice del caracter a reemplazar.
    @param car: Caracter de reemplazo.
    @return Texto con el reemplazo aplicado
    """
    lista = list(texto)
    lista[pos] = car
    return "".join(lista)

ejemplo="pytfon"
print(ejemplo)
ejemplo = replace_at(ejemplo, 3, "h")
print(ejemplo)
```

produce

```
pytfon
python
```